# GROUP BY gives "Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

So what I am trying to do is set Total_Credits as '12' for Certification, '30' for masters and '120 for bachelors. The Degree_Specialty is what I'm basing my code off of right below it. Im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. This data Im exporting to be an XLS file, however this one minor bug I can get.

> Column 'dls.dbo.Acad_Plan_Term.Acad_Plan_Type_Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Its when I change the values'CERT', 'BZ', 'MZ' to '30' '120' and '12' that I start getting these errors.

```
select 
 z.Degree_Title            
,z.Degree_Specialty
,z.Total_Credits

from
(select
     rtrim(ap.Acad_Plan_Code) as Degree_Title
    ,case when rtrim(ap.acad_plan_type_code) ='MST' and rtrim(ap.Degree_Code) IN ('EMBA','MA','MAA','MBA','MED','MS','MSEE') then ap.Degree_Code
          when rtrim(ap.acad_plan_type_code) ='MST' and rtrim(ap.Degree_Code) NOT IN ('EMBA','MA','MAA','MBA','MED','MS','MSEE') then 'MZ' 
          when rtrim(ap.Acad_Plan_Type_Code) in ('MAJ','BAS','EXT') and RTRIM(ap.Degree_Code) IN ('BA','BAAS','BAS','BBA','BHSA','BS') then ap.Degree_Code
          when rtrim(ap.Acad_Plan_Type_Code) in ('MAJ','BAS','EXT') and RTRIM(ap.Degree_Code) NOT IN ('BA','BAAS','BAS','BBA','BHSA','BS') then 'BZ'
          when Acad_Plan_Type_Code = 'CER' then 'CERT'
     end as Degree_Specialty


    ,case when rtrim(ap.acad_plan_type_code) ='MST' and rtrim(ap.Degree_Code) IN ('EMBA','MA','MAA','MBA','MED','MS','MSEE') then '30'
          when rtrim(ap.acad_plan_type_code) ='MST' and rtrim(ap.Degree_Code) NOT IN ('EMBA','MA','MAA','MBA','MED','MS','MSEE') then '30'
          when rtrim(ap.Acad_Plan_Type_Code) in ('MAJ','BAS','EXT') and RTRIM(ap.Degree_Code) IN ('BA','BAAS','BAS','BBA','BHSA','BS') then '120'
          when rtrim(ap.Acad_Plan_Type_Code) in ('MAJ','BAS','EXT') and RTRIM(ap.Degree_Code) NOT IN ('BA','BAAS','BAS','BBA','BHSA','BS') then '120'
          when Acad_Plan_Type_Code = 'CER' then '12'
     end as Total_Credits
...)z
```

Comment: As this does not show all the code it's difficult to tell. But it looks like you are doing some kind of aggregate function with a GROUP BY clause without grouping by the fields that are not being aggregated

Comment: There has been asked many, many times before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+is+invalid+in+the+select+list+because+it+is+not+contained+in+either+an+aggregate+function+or+the+GROUP+BY+clause

Comment: I don't see a `GROUP BY`.  That's the question.  If you don't put the group by, how do you expect people to help you?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is pretty much exactly as the error suggests. If you have a field in the `select` clause and you want to aggregate a field(s), then **all** fields which are not in the aggregate must be in the `group by` clause.

So, for example a valid grouping would be:

```sql
select
    departmant
    , sales_person
    , sum(sale_value)
from
   the_table
group by
    department
    , sales_person
```

You **cannot** leave `sales_person` out of the `group by` clause. If you don't want to group by it, you must leave it out of the select statement.

You haven't specified what database you're using, so it's difficult to give alternatives. your database ([oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23sql-1906475.html), [MSSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql), and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)) may support windowing.